# Selecting specific columns from multiple data-frame if the column name is same as the dataframe name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have multiple files, I need to select a specific column from each data frame and merge them finally.
Here are my data frame examples,

```
>> df1.head()

ID     df1    fox    mnd
ADF   49.0   34.0   55.7
XCF   89.7   32.8   21.7
```

And the second and third data frames are,

```
>> df2.head()

ID    lat2     df2     sap
ADF  67.00   84.00   95.70
XCF  59.70   62.80   11.70
BHG  89.00   54.89    0.34

>> df3.head()

ID     df1     df2     df3
ADF  56.00   84.00   95.70
XCF  59.70   62.80   11.70
CXD  89.90    0.90    1.56
```

And so on, I have 37 such data frames with different dimensions. What I am looking for are:

1. First, I need to select only columns which are same as file name. For example, from `df1` I need only column `df1`.
2. Finally, concatenate them all together as a single data frame.

The problem here is: for some of the data frames I have column names of with all filenames in the path, but for few data frames I do only have columns names with the filename and additional columns with other names. so my following piece of code is selecting all the columns from each data frames. Which is not what I am looking for.

```
path = 'usr/fils/data'
all_files = [os.path.join(path, i) for i in os.listdir(path) if i.endswith('tsv')]
filenames = [os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(files)) for files in all_files]
main = []

for files in all_files:
    for samids in filenames:
        dfs = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(files, sep="\t")
        dfs.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
        if samids in dfs.columns:
            pc_matrix = dfs[[samids]]
            main.append(pc_matrix)
merged = pd.concat(main, axis=1)
```

For example, here in this case `merged` data frame consists of all columns from three data frames. However, this is not what I want.

In the end, I need my data frame should look like,

```
>> df_final

ID     df1     df2     df3
ADF  49.00   84.00   95.70
XCF  89.70   62.80   11.70
BHG     NA   89.00      NA
CXD     NA      NA    1.56
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mytlp1t6bro1yly/AAAofCoHrwZTtnn04NFYGSb1a?dl=0
all_files = glob.glob('path/*')
main = []
for files in all_files:
    c = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(files))
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(files, usecols=[c] + ['ID'], index_col=['ID'], sep='\t')
        #if possible duplicated ID column - use mean or sum for unique values
        #df = df.mean(level=0)
        #df = df.sum(level=0)
        print (df)
        main.append(df)
    except:
        pass


merged = pd.concat(main,axis=1, sort=True)
print (merged)
      df1    df2    df3
ADF  49.0  84.00  95.70
BHG   NaN  54.89    NaN
CXD   NaN    NaN   1.56
XCF  89.7  62.80  11.70
```

Comment: Thank you for quick solution, however, the solution you provided complains, I have input dataframes of different row ids(row index). Therefore, the `concat` step is throwing error. Also the `usecols` is throwing error: 
```
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['df1']
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question, because the datafarmes are heterogeneous in terms of column name as well. Therefore, the `usecol` feature will not select the column of interest rather throws an error message.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but still it is returning empty `df`. And the so the concat steop is throwing error

Comment: hmm, somehow in the real dataset it is still not working

Comment: @user1017373 - are data splitted by `,` ? Or by tab? For tab need `df = pd.read_csv(files, usecols=[c] + ['ID'], index_col=['ID'], sep='\t')` - add separator tab

Comment: The data is seperated by tab

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, in the `main` variable something is added, however, the `merged` dataframe is empty.

Comment: At merge, 
   4841         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
   4842     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(
-> 4843         passed, implied))
   4844 
   4845 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (31, 8559), indices imply (31, 8558)

Comment: Duplicated columns within each dataframes?

Comment: @user1017373 - Added solution for avoid error if possible duplicated ID values

Comment: Thank you for the new solution, but may i know where is it mentioned to avoid the error if their is a duplicated `ID` value?

Comment: @user1017373 -  `df = df.mean(level=0)`

Comment: `df = df.mean(level=0)`, is not resolving the issue. I am accepting the answer. Thank you so much for your time.